# How do i fix external css code error on some specific attributes if those codes doesn't work on one page but work on another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on an login form and i have come across a situation where my border-bottom attribute does not work on it but that same works on another simple hello world page.

This is Windows 10 running on DELL INSPIRON 3000 Series. I use Sublime Text Editor for all my works. I have tried to run my CSS attribute `border-bottom` on one of my webpage that doesn't seem to work but that same piece of code worked perfectly fine on just simple hello world webpage.

```css
.login-box h1 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <h1> Login </h1>
  <div class="textbox"> 
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="username" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="password" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
```

I did expect a `5px` solid blue border below my heading in Webpage but it just doesn't work in it.

Comment: show your html pls

Comment: Use the development tools in your browser and inspect the element.  it will show you if a CSS rule is being overridden by another rule somwhere else.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the error in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Without HTML we can't possibly know what's going wrong. Consider editing your question.

Comment: <div class="login-box"> <h1> Login </h1> <div class="textbox"> <input type="text" name="" placeholder="username" value=""> <br> <br> </div> <div class="textbox"> <input type="password" name="" placeholder="password" value=""> <br> <br> </div> This is the part of the HTML code for the above CSS code.

Comment: @ShashankKumar The code you've provided does as you expect. Please make sure your code replicates the issue you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided above does what you expect it to do (go click the run code snippet). It might be overridden by some css that's why it's not working in your login page.

To force the browser to use your css without being overridden, try this.

```
.login-box h1 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue !important;
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: I have been successful in running the code in internal CSS but not as External.

Answer (score -1):

works fine... you need to have errors in your html
[check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59ewumd8/)

```
<div class="login-box">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: how can you provide an answer without his html?

Comment: <div class="login-box">
  <h1>  Login </h1>
  <div class="textbox">
    
   <input type="text" name=""  placeholder="username" value=""> <br> <br>
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
  
   <input type="password" name="" placeholder="password" value=""> <br> <br>
  </div>

   
    
This is the part of the HTML code for the above CSS code.